# How to do Auto Increment

Tags: swift, realm

After reading the documentation I was not able to know how can I create a table with primary key integer with autoincrement attribute. Im using swift.

```
import UIKit
import Realm

class Person: RLMObject {
    var name = ""
    var birthdate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
    var dogs = RLMArray(objectClassName: Dog.className())
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I refer Realm data its drawback, visit
<http://stackoverflow.com/a/26257616/373262>?

Answer (score 0):

I think to set a primary key (assuming you are ok with strings) you should use:

```
class Person: RLMObject {
    var id = ""
    var name = ""
    var birthdate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
    var dogs = RLMArray(objectClassName: Dog.className())

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Then you need to use unique id's when you set the Person.id. Here is a related question that discusses that [How do I set a auto increment key in Realm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252432/how-do-i-set-a-auto-increment-key-in-realm)